# Sencha Touch: itemTpl loop?

Tags: templates, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Say the input data is a json like:

```
{   "facet_fields":{
        "cat":[
            "electronics",3,
            "card",2,
            "graphics",2,
            "music",1
        ]}}
```

The array "cat" is recovered and should be displayed using a for loop. I'm stuck at this point :)

The code so far:

```
Ext.define('Sandbox.view.FacetList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'facet-list',

    config: {
        baseCls: 'article-list',
        itemTpl: '' +
            '<div class="article">' +
                '<tpl for="categories">' +
                      '<div>Item {#}</div>' +
                 '</tpl>' +
            '</div>'
    }

});
```

This outputs: `Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4`

and I'd like to see the following output:
`electronics (3), card (2), graphics (2), music (1)`

Can't find the right way.
thanks for your time :-)
J.

Comment: why is your node named `cat` while using `tpl for "categories"` ? And also, your data seems weird...   `"electronics",3,
            "card",2,
            "graphics",2,
            "music",1`, do you mean `"electronic" : 3`... ?

Comment: yep indeed, typo "cat". The data is output by Apache SOLR, I'd have loved to get electronic:3,graphics:2,(...) but it's a plain array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a model and a store for your data? If so, I suggest you use the [convert](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert) method available in fields. It will allow you to convert that `cat` field into better data that the `tpl` can understand.

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'cat',
                convert: function(values, record) {
                    var data = [],
                        ln = values.length,
                        i, name, value;

                    // loop through each of the array values
                    for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
                        // if it is a name, save it
                        if (i % 2 == 0) {
                            name = values[i];
                        }

                        // if it is a value, save the value and push 
                        // to the data array
                        if (i % 2 == 1) {
                            value = values[i];

                            data.push({
                                name: name,
                                value: value
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    // return the data array for this field
                    return data;
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
});
```

And then you can use it in your `tpl` like this:

```
tpl: [
    '<tpl for="cat">',
        '{name}: {value}, '
    '</tpl>'
].join()
```

Comment: Looks great, impatient to try this out!

Comment: Great example. Very helpful